# ad characters to all strings in array php

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have a form where someone would enter "xbrand tv" for a real example, lets say, "sony tv" I am then passing the data to the next page using the post method.

I'm using in_array to direct the results correctly. The way the code is set up below, if someone entered 'sony television' it would display the else statement.

```
$product_add = $_POST['syd'];
$pa = strtolower($product_add);
$tv= array('sony tv', 'vizio tv', 'panasonic tv', 'lg tv', 'samsung tv', 'phillips tv', 'sharp tv', 'dynex tv', 'toshiba tv');
    if (in_array($pa, $tv))
    {
            //do stuff
           }
else {
    // do something else
}
```

Obviously I can add 'sony television' to the array but I feel like there has to be a more efficient way to do it.

I would like to have my $tv array look like this:

```
$tv= array('sony', 'vizio', 'panasonic', 'lg', 'samsung', 'phillips', 'sharp', 'dynex', 'toshiba');
```

and make it so if "sony tv" or "sony television" were entered in the initial form, it would be true to the initial if statement. Is that possible? If so, how should I go about it?

Comment: Many ways to go about it. Iterate over the array of brands and check if each brand is found in the input rather than an exact match.

Comment: I updated the question to be more specific but  basically rather than have 'sony tv' and 'sony television' in the array, I just want to have 'sony' @marty

Comment: Yes, so you take the phrase entered i.e. 'sony television', iterate over the list of brands, and check whether each brand name exists within the entered phrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**strpos()**](https://www.php.net/strpos) to check if the string entered contains any of the brands listed in your array. This should work for you:

```
$product_add = $_POST['syd'];
$pa = strtolower($product_add);
$tv = array('sony', 'vizio', 'panasonic', 'lg', 'samsung', 'phillips', 'sharp', 'dynex', 'toshiba');
$found = false;
foreach ($tv as $brand) {
    if (strpos($pa, $brand) !== false) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if ($found)
{
    // Found one of the brand names in the user's string
}
else {
    // Did not find one of the brand names in the user's string
}
```